# How to post-process Input HTML text to prevent WAF/OWASP errors?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, cloudflare, ckeditor4.x

I use:

DB: SQL Server
Server: MVC5 / C# / .NET 4.7
Firewall: Cloudflare WAF
Client: HTML, CSS, Javascriptm JQuery.

I use the Cloudflare WAF for my application which accepts HTML elements in the richtext edit field. I use the CKEditor to enable these edit fields. However I am finding that much of the pasted HTML text is triggering the WAF OWASP rules, and in many cases as a false positive.

One can Base-64 encode the string clientside, but this may mask dodgey string from the WAF. For example  will still run when decoded back into the browser.

What is a good approach for dealing with this issue? The only other ideas I have had is to

a) Only allow plain text which would be restrictive.
b) Use some form of clientside cleaning utility to sanitize the text before it is uploaded to remove any dodgey code.

I would welcome some best practice advice and any tools that I could investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

Encoding data before the WAF and decode it before database insertion is actually bypassing the WAF, disabling it would be just the same.

Now, in your case you are dealing with html, you could html_encode it. This would have no impact when dispaying it, but this could mean you would have to decode it before using it in an user input, otherwise you could face nested html_encoding on submit.

As I'm not sure of the best way to deal with this, I'm also looking for best practices on how to allow free user input without falsely triggering the WAF. If anyone finds something, please share it.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but would it help to make a server-side distinction between trusted and untrusted data?  You say encoding the user input defeats the purpose of the WAF, but that's only the case for text you already know is untrusted user input.  So the WAF still adds value for any other data being passed through, doesn't it?  Why not encode the data that you plan to treat as untrusted on the server side and let the WAF block everything else.  Then, server-side, you can sanitize the encoded data before passing it downstream.